# How can I inject an iframe into facebook through chrome extension development?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

It's quite simple. I want to inject an iframe on facebook through an extension that I'm developing, but facebook has X-FRAME headers set to not accept external domains.

I tried to use , but even with the right permissions document.createElement('webview') just creates an empty tag (even with the proper css and src)

Comment: there's no way facebook would let you inject an iframe on their site

Comment: webview isn't an iframe, you can't inject it in a site. You can inject an iframe that points to a page in your extension, which in turn has an iframe that loads an external site.

Comment: Well, I think it does: https://imgur.com/a/gXICayl